# Mongo User Defined Functions and Map Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, user-defined-functions

Is there a way in mongo to create user-defined Javascript functions. I have several Map/Reduce functions on the client side that i would like to use within other MR functions.

For example, several MR functions calculate all sorts of averages. I want to be able to use them like so :

```
function reduce(k,v)
{
    if (val > myDatabaseAverage())
    // ..do something
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
db.system.js.save( { _id : "myDatabaseAverage" , value : function(){
  // ..do something 
} } );
```

That will store the JS function on the server and can be accessed by m/r from that point on.

For further examples see : [mongo/jstests/core/mr_stored.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/d80312792b116f68bb3dd19d92e6c8f84c48f177/jstests/core/mr_stored.js)

Comment: should it not be "myDatabaseAverage" instead?

Comment: The mongo tests use `db.system.js.insert()` now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Remon van Vliet,

You will have to use,

```
db.system.js.save( { _id : "myDatabaseAverage" , 
                     value : function(){ // ..do something } 
                 } );
```

to save your function first,

and then you need to call,

```
db.loadServerScripts();
```

before you execute your function.