# Use npm module in MongoDB map-reduce

Tags: mongodb, npm

I would like to use [rus-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rus-diff) in as reduce-step in a map-reduce job but can't find how to make it available.

Comment: A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/6491769/189699

Comment: The related question is indeed how to make additional JS functions available in Map/Reduce. Since the functionality you're looking to add is part of an npm package you'll have to extract and test the relevant functions. I would also look into whether your desired calculation is possible using [set operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#set-expressions) in the Aggregation Framework (MongoDB 2.6+) or post details (i.e. sample document and expected results) as a separate question. In general the Aggregation Framework should be more performant than Map/Reduce.